# Are these functions isomorphisms of the first binary structure with the second? - Fraleigh p.34 3.13, 3.15

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

(1.) How can we suspect these two aren't isomorphisms, before trying to find counterexamples?
 (2.) I  don't understand their arguments. 
For 13, how is there no $x$ such that $\begin{align} \phi(f)(x) & = x + 1 \\ \int^{x}_{0} f(t) dt &= \end{align}$?

For 15, how is there no $x$ such that $\begin{align} \phi(f)(x) &= 1 \\ x\cdot f(x)& = \end{align}$ ? Don't know what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: You cannot suspect it, you just have to figure it out. Either find a proof or counterexample. A map can fail to be an isomorphism because of only three reason: it's not injective or not surjective or not homomorphism. So check each property in turn.

Comment: @Frank Muer: Have you finished this question?

Comment: @B.S. I think I made some progress on it. I wrote out an answer from Marek's hints. But I don't see the prognostications (please see profile). So I haven't finished the question because it still feels magical.

Comment: @Marek Thanks. How can you make the two prognostications (please see my profile) in my answer? or is there some easier way?

Comment: @FrankMuer: Let me see it please. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am posting about $15$. What we are looking for $15$. Indeed, we want to examine the map $\phi$ for being an isomorphism. Any such that map should be a well-defined homomorphism and be a bijection form $F$ to $F$.

- it is well-defined function:

$$f(x)=g(x)\Longrightarrow \phi [f(x)]=x\cdot f(x)=x\cdot g(x)=\phi[g(x)]$$

- It is an homomorphism between groups:

$$\phi(f)\phi(g)(x)=\phi(f)\left(x\cdot g(x)\right)=x\cdot f(x)\cdot g(x)=x\cdot(fg)(x)=\phi(fg)(x)$$

- Is it one-one map? If it wants to be like that, we should verify the following statement:

$$\phi(f)=\phi(g)\Longrightarrow f=g$$ If $\phi(f)=\phi(g)$ so every real $x$ we have $\phi(f)(x)=\phi(g)(x)$, so we have $$x\cdot f(x)=x\cdot g(x)$$ Can we cancel that irritating $x$ form both sides? No! Unless we assume $x\neq 0$. This is the point that counterexample appears. In fact the values of $\phi$ when acting on every two non-equal functions $f$ and $g$ in $F$ while $x=0$ are the same. Therefore $\phi$ cannot satisfy the injectivity and so it is not an isomorphism. If we want to work the sample the book gave us, we can say:

Let $\phi$ is an isomorphism. So it is onto from $F$ to $F$. So for example, if we set $\color{darkcyan}{f=1}\in \langle F,\cdot\rangle$ in the right hand side, then we should have $g\in\langle F,\cdot\rangle $ on left hand side such that $$\phi(g)(x)=\color{darkcyan}{f=1}, ~~x\in\mathbb  R$$ Now what would be happen if we have $$\phi(g)(x)=x\cdot g(x)=1$$ while $x=0$?? Indeed, we would get: $$0=\phi(g)(0)=0\cdot g(0)=1$$
This is a nice contradiction.

Comment: @amWhy I agree with all of you. I Upvoted.

Comment: @B.S. I think you mean $\phi$ is not injective because you showed $\phi(f) = \phi(g) \implies f \neq g$, when $x = 0$. Can you plase explain why $g(x) = 1/x$ doesn't belong to $<F, \cdot>$? It has derivatives of all orders? I see it's not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: @FrankMuer: Ops! I thought that you are given that $F$ consist of all **differentiable** functions. Sorry. Indeed, Marek pointed this part of problem very good and I don't see anything special to add. Thanks for the remark. :)

Comment: @FrankMuer: As far as I remember, I assume the operation is function multiplication, unless, I think, we get some troubles to prove it is a homomorphism.

Comment: @B.S. Thanks. But it looks like you calculated it like function composition? You did $\phi(f)\color{magenta}{\phi(g)(x)} = \phi(f)\left(\color{magenta}{x\cdot g(x)}\right)
$ Not $\phi(f)\color{blue}{\phi(g)(x)} = \phi(f)(x) \cdot \color{blue}{\phi(g)(x)}$ ?

Comment: @FrankMuer: I don't think so :-) If I used the F.C. so we wouldn't have $\phi(f)(x\cdot g(x))=\phi(f(x))\cdot g(x)$.

Comment: @B.S. Thanks. You're right! I was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @B.S. Is it ok if you look at my answer at the bottom? I'm trying to do this for 13 but I don't see anything wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

1. For 13, compute the value of $\phi(f)(0)$ for any $f$ whatsoever. Does $x+1$ have this value at $0$ as well?
2. For 15, compute the value of $\phi(f)(0)$ for any $f$ whatsoever. Does constant $1$ function have this value at $0$ as well?

Answer (score 1):

B.S. answered 15 nicely and exquisitely. I try to do the sae for 13.

• Is it a well-defined function? Yes. I can see this.

• Is it an homomorphism between groups:

$\begin{align}( \, \phi(f) + \phi(g) \, )(x) & = \int_{[0, x]}f(t) + g(t) \, dt \\ & = \int_{[0, x]}f(t) \, dt + \int_{[0, x]} g(t) \, dt = \phi(f)(x) + \phi(g)(x) \end{align}$. Yes.

• Is it one-to-one map? $\phi(f)=\phi(g)\Rightarrow \color{purple}{\frac{d}{dx}} \int_{[0, x]}f(t) \, dt = \color{purple}{\frac{d}{dx}} \int_{[0, x]}g(t) \, dt \implies f(x) = g(x) $. Yes.

• Is it onto map? For all $r(x) \in <F, +>,$ is there $f(x)$ such that $\phi(f)(x) = r(x)$?

Start from what you need to prove to find $f(x)$. $\phi(f)(x) = r(x) \implies \int_{[0, x]}f(t) \, dt = r(x) \implies \color{purple}{\frac{d}{dx}}  \int_{[0, x]}f(t) \, dt = r(x) \implies f(x) = r'(x) $. 
Yes.

Where's the problem?

Comment: @user I forgot. Thanks for reminding me. I upvoted. I won't accept yet because I'm not finished.

Comment: It was not magic :) If you work on your own and try to prove e.g. injectivity, you are quickly lead to consider values at $x=0$. After that, any function that is not equal to $0$ at $x=0$ works. Thankfully, B.S. posted full details, check his answer.